# inserir virgulas em alinhas de arquivo.txt

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir virgulas em *arquivo.txt*, por exemplo

> ```
> 000000005200040630161811301230
> 000000006200052200050001000200
> 000000007200061318223617001730
> ```

para ficar assim:

> ```
> 000000005,2000406,301618113012,30
> 000000006,2000522,000500010002,00
> 000000007,2000613,182236170017,30
> ```

Comment: Qual o critério para inserção das virgulas?

Comment: primeira virgula após 9 caracteres, segunda virgula após 1 carácter, terceira virgula apos 4 caracteres

Comment: Sempre vai seguir esse padarão para todas as linhas

Comment: qual sistema? Linux ou windows?

Comment: Estou utilizando o windows

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser utilizada a função substr do php conforme vai lendo o arquivo txt, assim:

```
$origem = 'origem.txt';
$destino = 'destino.txt';

$arqOri = fopen($origem, 'r'); // Abre o arquivo de origem para leitura
$arqDes = fopen($destino, 'w'); // Cria o arquivo como destino

while (!feof($arqOri)){
   $str = fread($arqOri);
   $strNovo = substr($str, 0, 9) . ',' .
              substr($str, 9, 7) . ',' .
              substr($str, 15, 12);
   fwrite($arqDes, $strNovo);
}

fclose($arqOri);
fclose($arqDes);
```

Dessa forma você está abrindo um arquivo, lendo linha a linha e ajustando a informação, gravando em outro arquivo.

Nesse caso, se o arquivo de destino existir ele será sobrescrito com o novo conteúdo.

Comment: É que são muitas linhas,  gostaria de puxar diretamente de um arquivo.txt

Comment: Você está usando o "fopen" para abrir o arquivo txt? Vou inserir no código um exemplo de como utilizá-lo.

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando